# How to set input box width evenly when input bars are horizontally placed?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Good day,

I am an absolute beginner to CSS and am trying to align two input fields horizontally (basically I want "create an account" bars on the left half of the page and "sign in" on the right side). Even though I have, more or less, aligned given input fields I can't size the right ones properly.

I used `width:40%` for the fields on the left and it did its job. The fields became bigger and cover the part that I need. However, if I increase the width of the "right" ones they just get pushed to the left but overall size of the bar stays the same.

I tried changing positions and so on but to no avail. Usually it just breaks the whole design.

Part of HTML code:

```
<div class="content">
        <div class="signInContent">
            <h1> Sign In </h1>
            <p> Already have an account? </p>
            <hr>

            <label for="email"><b>Email <br></b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="registerContent">
            <h1> Register </h1>
            <p>Please fill in the form to create an account.</p>
            <hr>

            <label for="email"><b>Email</b><br></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Part of CSS code (first left side then right side)

```
.content input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  width: 40%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  border: 3px solid #4CAF50;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #f2f2f2;
}

.registerContent input[type=text]:focus, input[type=password]:focus {
  width: 41%;
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.signInContent {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}

.signInContent input[type=text]:focus, input[type=password]:focus {
  width: 55%;
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

Basically, the alignment is correct. The width of "left" fields is sized correctly (the field is actually 40%), however the right one only stays about 20% just gets pushed to the left (with white space to its right).

The only idea that I have that "may" fix the problem is making tables with HTML but I am unsure whether it will work or not and until I undertake such process I thought I would ask here. I think there has to be some easier solution. I get to see web-sites with such content all the time.

Also, This is my first post on stackoverflow so if I did something incorrectly please inform me so that I can correct the mistakes.

To explain better, below is how the page looks. I want the right "fields" to be the same size as the left ones

[image]

Comment: How are you getting the `.signInContent` to the right side? Are you using `float: right`, or something else?

Comment: Yes I use 
``````````````
float: right; 
``````````````
Sorry I forgot to input that part of the code. Edited.

Comment: Part of the issue is that `div.registerContent` is a different width than `div.signInContent`. One way to handle this is to float both divs, instead of just one.

Comment: I set the float value of .registerContent to "left" and I can't even describe how it messed up the design :D I set both width to the same value but the only thing I got is the "right" fields got pushed to the right. :\

Comment: The benefit of floating both of them is so that they both get treated the same way, for example, when you set a percentage for the width. I posted a working version; however, in the full code-base, you may need to make some additional tweaks to get it all to work well.

Comment: If you float them both, you want to make sure that there are no other children inside the `.content` div.

Comment: I guess you are dealing with float behavior. you need to reset the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context and resize the inputs :  demo/result https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/KYYQPm using  `div.registerContent {
  overflow:hidden
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is that `div.signInContent` is only half the width of `div.content`, while `div.registerContent` is the full width of `div.content`. That matters because percentage values (like `width: 40%`) are relative to the same value (i.e width) of the parent element.

Floating both divs fixes this issue:

```
.content div {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Then, you see that both divs show the original problem. This might feel like a step backwards, but now we can treat both divs the same way. 40% of 100 is the same as 80% of 50; so, let's use 80% instead of 40%:

```
.content input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  width: 80%;
  ...
}
```

And, here's the full, working demo

```css
.content input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  border: 3px solid #4CAF50;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #f2f2f2;
}

.registerContent input[type=text]:focus, input[type=password]:focus {
  width: 55%;
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.content div {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
.signInContent input[type=text]:focus, input[type=password]:focus {
  width: 55%;
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
        <div class="signInContent">
            <h1> Sign In </h1>
            <p> Already have an account? </p>
            <hr>

            <label for="email"><b>Email <br></b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="registerContent">
            <h1> Register </h1>
            <p>Please fill in the form to create an account.</p>
            <hr>

            <label for="email"><b>Email</b><br></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you for your explanation! I understand the problem now!

Comment: FWIW, there are ready-made libraries for handling this problem --- such as [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com) ---, typically by using a "grid,"  or by using flexbox, as Bryce demonstrates.

Comment: @GArts you are actually dealing with float and need to know about : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context another way to sort this out https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/KYYQPm

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to size and position the div containers and then make the inputs 100% of the width of their containers. Though I notice you're making some of the inputs wider on focus. What's the reason for that?

**Here's an example using floats (an extension of your question):**

(using simple percents here won't work because the padding is ADDED to the width eg 40% + 20px + 20px + 60% + 20px + 20px = 100% and 80px) `calc` lets CSS do the math for that to equal 100%

Also, make sure to "clear" your floats so they don't mess with other page content. Here's a [good way](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) to do that.

```css
.leftSide, .rightSide {
 padding: 20px;
}
.leftSide {
 float: left;
 width: calc(60% - 40px);
 background: #dadada;
}
.rightSide {
 float: right;
 width: calc(40% - 40px);
 background: #eee;
}

input {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="leftSide">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
 </div>
 <div class="rightSide">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
 </div>
</div>
```

**And a better solution using CSS flexbox**

`flex-box` is "better" than using floats since its more resilient when you use different sizes, it will make the columns the same height, AND `float` can often "bleed" outside its container to impact other things on the page if you don't `clear` the floats.

```css
.container {
 display:flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
.leftSide, .rightSide {
 padding: 20px;
}
.leftSide {
 flex-basis: calc(60% - 40px);
 background: #dadada;
}
.rightSide {
 flex-basis: calc(40% - 40px);
 background: #eee;
}

input {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="leftSide">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
 </div>
 <div class="rightSide">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like that you've added a flexbox version; however, you should explain what makes it better.

Comment: This sounds fantastic. I will have a look at flex-boxes.

Comment: @GArts Take a look at this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ It will help with learning Flexbox